# SMTP success but the email is not delivered

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a newbie to CodeIgntier. I'm trying to setup SMTP on CodeIgniter. I receive a success message on page but email is not delivered. Can somebody help me?

```
 $config = Array(
                        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                        'smtp_port' => 465,
                        'smtp_user' => 'xxx@gmail.com',
                        'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
                        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
                    );
                    $this->load->library('email', $config);
                    $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com', 'Admin Team');
                    $sendTo = $this->input->post('email');
                    $message= 'Hello';


                    $this->email->to($sendTo);
                    $this->email->subject('Verification Email');
                    $this->email->message($message);
                    if($this->email->send()){
                        echo "Success";
                    }
```

Comment: what does codeigniter email debugger returns ? $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: i've tried that but it returns nothing...

Comment: make sure that OpenSSL  extension is up an running

Comment: yes it's already running. Btw,  
is there any possibilities that my computer setting could be the cause? because I've tried in another computer and it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `xxx@gmail.com`. In google there is Security protection call [**2-Step Verification**](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/). Make sure its there,If there remove it and try

There is no fault in your code. . To remove it check [this link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en)

Comment: it is already removed,still, i can't receive the email. But thanks for your answer :D

Comment: is there any possibilities that my computer setting could be the cause? because I've tried in another computer and it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code seems ok, make sure your server has openssl extension up and running , and check your firewall for the used smtp port (465 in your case). I would also recommend you using the third party library  phpmailer from https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer whic (mostly for sending html in your message and links )

cheers!